# Postgres: Use JSONB column keys as generated stored column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, generated-columns

I have a table which has a jsonB column named as `emailAddress`. An example row in that column is like this:

```
{
  "john.doe@best.com": {
    "tags": {
    "work": true
  }
},
  "nate.calman@best.com": {
    "tags": {
      "work": true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a new column named `lookup` which is generated based on the keys of the `emailAddress` column. So the value of `lookup` column of the above example should be something like:

`john.doe@best.com nate.calman@best.com`

This will obviously update if more keys are added to the `emailAddress` column.

I started with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE "table_example"
ADD COLUMN lookup TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (jsonb_object_keys("emailAddresses")) STORED;
```

But the error I get is:
`ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in column generation expressions`

I understand that this is not the right way to do it because no where I m specifying the `separator` I want to use. I tried using multiple functions like `array()` or `array_agg()` to get this to a form accepted by generated column, but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change your data model, have a table of e-mail addresses and use foreign keys.

Comment: Why do you want to add that column? What problem are you trying to solve with that? You are adding another layer of de-normalization to an already de-normalized model.

Comment: I want adding the `lookup` column to add a gin index on it and make it easy on search. This is just an example, I have other columns also that i will put in the lookup column.

Answer (score 0):

Better build a view instead. Use lateral join

```sql
create view the_view as
select t.*, l.keys as lookup
from the_table as t 
left join lateral
(
  select string_agg(k, ' ') as keys  
  from jsonb_object_keys(mailAddress) as k
) as l on true;
```

or a scalar subquery

```sql
create view the_view as
select t.*, 
 (
   select string_agg(k, ' ') as keys  
   from jsonb_object_keys(mailAddress) as k
 ) as lookup
from the_table as t;
```

Comment: A `left join` is probably better than the `cross join` - otherwise rows without any emails won't show up in the view.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

```
create or replace function remove_nested_object(obj jsonb, key_to_remove text)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(key, value- key_to_remove)
    from jsonb_each(obj)
$$;

ALTER TABLE  "table_example"
    ADD COLUMN lookup TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      translate(remove_nested_object("emailAddresses", 'tags') #>> '{}',':{}",','')
    ) STORED;
```